# UIImageView Array not showing contents?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an array of `UIImageViews` that I want to display to the screen. However, I can't seem to be able to do so. I declared my array of `UIImageViews` like so:

```
class EventCell: UITableViewCell, CellDelegate{   
    @IBOutlet var eventName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var eventLocation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var attendeesImages: [UIImageView]!
}
```

And I have a function that displays the `EventCell` contents like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Dequeue a "reusable" cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(eventCellIdentifier) as! EventCell
    setCellContents(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

//Set contents of Event Cell.. self.events is a global array
//which have information that EventCell objects need to display

func setCellContents(cell:EventCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
    let item = self.events[indexPath.section]
    var count = 0

    cell.eventName.text = item.eventName()
    cell.eventLocation.text = item.eventLocation()

    cell.attendeesImage.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)//Remove old images before adding new
    for value in item.attendeesImage {
        let newImageView = UIImageView(image : value)
        newImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        newImageView.layer.cornerRadius = newImageView.frame.size.width / 2
        cell.attendeesImage.append(newImageView)
        println("Count inside: \(cell.attendeesImage.count)")
    }
}
```

I printed out the `count` of the `cell.attendeesImage` to ensure that no extraneous images were being added and it seemed to prove correct. However, I have no idea why my images are not displaying. I made sure to hook the `cell.attendeesImage` as an IBCollection in my Storyboard (since it is an Array) in my `EventCell`.  Any ideas for why this isn't showing up? Thanks!

Comment: How do you layout your images in your table view cell?

Comment: @ozgur that step I haven't accomplished yet and I'm not entirely sure on how to do this portion either. I was going to look into it after I fixed this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you haven't implemented that part, then I don't quite understand what your problem is. Where is the code responsible for displaying images in your cell? Did you check if you've added image views in your cell content like `cell.contentView.addSubview(newImageView)`

Comment: @ozgur well to display the images, I merely connected the `cell.attendeesImages` array to a `UIImageView` on the Story board. In that way, I could ensure that at least one image would show where I played the `UIImageView` if my code worked.  After I got that working, I was then planning on working on making the rest of the images appear. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nope. You can't pair an array of views with an image view in your IB. What you should do is to remove `@IBOutlet` from `attendeesImages`, initialize it as an empty array in your cell's `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier:)` method and manually add image views to both your array and your cell's `contentView` in `setCellContents` method.

Comment: @ozgur hm okay. I will try to look into this. So would you reccomend the best place to look is to look up how to do this is to look up  tutorials on `cell.contentView` and `cell.subView`?

Comment: Although creating new instances of UIImageView is not good approach, you'll need to addSubView your new instances of UIImageView to display on the cells.

Comment: @Shoaib If I end up using the `addSubView` method, if I'm not mistaken, I have to hard-code the position of that `subView` in my function, correct? Also can you clarify what you mean by creating new instances of `UIImageView` is not good approach? What would you reccomend?

Comment: I recommend to reuse same instances of UIImageViews that are already on your xib.

Comment: BTW where is the collection of imageFileNames to show on your imageViews?

Comment: @Shoaib I grab each image from using the Facebook API. It is then stored into the `item. attendeesImage` right before I invoke the `setCellContents` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong the collection outlet "attendeesImages".

When the view is loaded, the array attendeesImages are created and initialized with the image views you have created in interface builder. But then, if you remove all that references, you have lost the link between the outlets and the real views. The new image views you are creating are not the ones in the cell. They are still subviews of the cell, but now you have not a iboutlet references to them.

The solution: don't remove the values from the array. Just modify the image in each image view.

Comment: the total number of images at each cell may be different so removing everything in `prepareForReuse` and re-populating them again in the delegate method makes more sense to me.

Comment: Ah okay. So I took out the line     `cell.attendeesImage.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)` but that seems to make things worse. In fact, when I print out the `cell.attendeesImage.count`, the count continually increases which I would imagine is affecting what is actually being displayed. Any fixes around this?

Comment: @ozgur do you mind giving me an outline of the things you mentioned above?

Comment: @user1871869 not only remove that line. Also, change the append operation with the change of image in the imageView. That is, don't create a new imageView but set cell.attendeesImages[i] to item.attendeesImage[i].

Comment: @Gabriel I don't think that would work though because the size of the `cell.attendeesImages` would not be allocated and if I try to access `cell.attendeesImages[i]` then I would get an error saying `Array index out of bounds`. The reason I know this is because I have tried this out.

Comment: you have defined that property as a @IBOutlet. So, I suppose that you have created some imageviews and have linked them to that IBOutlet. Haven't you? Then YES, when the view is loaded the IBOutlet array instance is initialized. That is what IBOutlets are for.